# Can you control a Kafka Producer as to when it sends a message to the Kafka Brokers

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I'm developing a WebAPI for clients to call with messages that get published to a Kafka topic.  In most cases the client is only calling the WebAPI with a few messages.  On the WebAPI I'm getting an exception

> Local: Message timed out

This occurs right at around 5 minutes after the ProduceAsync call.

I've read lots of SO on using flush() and other producer config parameters to get the messages to the Kafka Brokers however those answers appears to be old and things have probably changed.  This is a C# implementation and I'm using the .Net Confluent wrappers.  I'm using the default for all the Producer Config parameters.

Can anyone provide guidance on the proper or hacky way of forcing the few messages from the WebApi to the Kafka Brokers?

Comment: Answers with `Flush` aren't old.

Comment: I believe it's related to the following: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1057